# Can I rely on componentWillMount to process changes in query parameters?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Is it true, that each of exists browsers always will reload page completely if I change the query parameters in the address bar?

If it's true I suppose, that I can rely at `componentWillMount`, because page always will be completely refreshing, but if it's false, should I prefer to process changes in the address bar in the `componentWillReceiveProps`?

Comment: Both componentWillMount and componentWillReceiveProps are deprecated, and it's recommended not to use these lifecycle methods anymore.

Comment: I know, but it's too expensive to switch to the new approach now. But in any case, how should I manage changes of query parameters now?

Comment: @nitrovatter updates to the query parameters can occur from the `history` API / Object as well. In that case the page is not reloaded. Just some events are fired so the page can react to the changes. For example run `history.replaceState(null, null, '/?someparam=5')` in your console and see what happens in the url.